# Ajax PUT method not hitting the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login form and I am trying to login using a PUT method as to store the logged-in username. But for some reason it's not hitting the server and not logging in. Could you please help?

I want this to go to the login page and failing to do so. Please help

Below is the code for the same:

HTML:

```
<form name="login" class="login-form request-form form-horizontal" method="post" id="login-user">
    <p class="pl-sign">Please Sign In</p>
    <div class="form-group" id="login-fields">
        <div class="cols-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"><span class="text--white glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="login-fields">
        <div class="cols-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"><span class="text--white glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></i>
                </span>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="view sign-in-app" type="submit" value="Sign In" id="submit-login" />
    <div class="forgot-up">
        <a href="#">forgot username/password ?</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#login-user").validate({

    submitHandler: userLogin

});
function userLogin() {

    var username = $('#user').val();
    var password = $('#pass').val();

    var data = $("#login-user").serialize();


    var userUrl = 'http://website.com/DatabaseName/Tablename/' + username + '/login?' + password + '';

    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({

        url: userUrl,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: data,

        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 0) {

                window.location.href = "http://website.com/page2.html";


            } else if (data == -1) {

                ("#error").html('<span class="error">Incorrect username or password</span>');

            } else {

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function() {

                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ' + data + ' !</div>');

                });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You've confirmed in the browser developer tools console tab that no network request is being sent or no response is being received from the server? Your `$.ajax` has no error handler, so add one, to see what the error is (if there is an error in the request)

Comment: One other issue is, when a form is submitted, a new page is loaded. In this case, as you have no `action` attribute in the form, the current page will be reloaded, probably before your ajax gets to do anything at all. you need to prevent the default behaviour of a `submit` to stop this from happening - as you are using jQuery, I wouldn't know the best way to do that

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your comments on it. I am trying to resolve it and having no luck yet.

Comment: keywords are `event` and  `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a form submit to  laod a new page (or relaod the current one if action isn't defined in the form), use preventDefault() method on the passed in event to the event handler

```
function userLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
... rest of your code
```

I'm assuming

```
submitHandler: userLogin
```

in the validate object will pass on the event object